# Every time I open the software center I get "failed to execute child process"

Tags: updates

Every time I try to use the software center I get the following error `Failed to execute child process` any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**try purging software center:**


CTRL + ALT + T:
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center

Comment: did you try this command on terminal `sudo apt-get purge -s software-center` ?